# Zend Framework optimization, tcpsndbuf & kmemsize

Tags: apache-2.2, memory, zend-framework, kmemsize

We're on the mid-tier DV Rage server on media temple using Zend Framework, and we've been getting QoS warnings in Virtuzzo pretty consistantly. We've spent the last week installing APC (tweaking that to death), mysql and apache tweaks (many recommended by Media Temple), front end gzip, Zend_View caching, and every optimization technique recommended in the Zend manual. At this point, I think we've gotten over our kmemsize issues mostly, but we are still getting tcpsndbuf warnings and I honestly don't know what to do with those. Our traffic is around 1000 uniques a day and I'm having a hard time believing that we can't support that. MT seems to be kind of "stingy" with the memory and after all this work optimizing, the answer seems to be "add more memory/upgrade"

1. Should we just stop "playing server" and start recommending actual dedicated servers for our clients?
2. Does anyone have any recommendations as to how much memory we need to be running a Zend Framework-based site...assuming our current of "1GB of dedicated RAM" (what it says in the marketing)?

I know this is a lot to ask, but we're at our wits end and we're more "code" than "server" people (so apologies in advance if any of this sounded stupid). :)

**Edit.** Ok, so of our 512MBs, (mt) has allocated 13MB to kmemsize. Is this ridiculously low? I feel like it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ask MT to alter your kmemsize allocation, or do this yourself, there should be a way to control it with `vzctl`.

Personally, with only 1000 uniques per day, I'm surprised you actually need a VPS at all, then again I'm using performance-oriented shared hosting, and most people know and use shared hosting that has "UNLIMITED TERABYTES".

Comment: Talked to them this morning and they won't change it and it can't be changed. Looking to switch hosts I think :) Thanks!